# Iterate through map in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, iterator

I have the following document:

```
{
    _id : new Object(...) 
    "school" : {
        "students" : {
            "72" : "John",
            "73" : "David",
        }
    }
}
```

I want to iterate through all the students, but I can't, because I can not access
`school.students`, `school.forEach` or `school.students.forEach`.

Globally, my task is to find all schools, having "John" as a student. The thing is `72` or `73` is internal id and can be different numbers

Comment: You can use the aggregate operator `$objectToArray` - and then iterate over using array operator like `$filter`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by

```
for (var key in school.students) {
            var value = school.students[key];
            print(value)
}
```